# Extremely strange class mess

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an action menu and I'm trying to start another activity once an icon is clicked, but it leads to a error panic. Actually it seems that it gets a wrong path to the class. Here is what I mean. here the code is:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.mapIcon) {
            Intent displayTheMap = new Intent(this, TheMap.class);
                    startActivity(displayTheMap);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

but it returns:

```
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gs.maps/com.gs.maps.TheMap}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f06003f (com.gs.maps:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b3d8a760 #0 id=0x7f06003f}
```

Why is this happening? It is supposed to find `com.gs.maps.TheMap` and not `com.gs.maps/com.gs.maps.TheMap` why is it getting an all wrong path? What am I missing? I know that it is a small part, but I'm unable to find a solution at this moment.

Full logcat exceptions:

```
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): Process: com.gs.maps, PID: 2079
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gs.maps/com.gs.maps.TheMap}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f06003f (com.gs.maps:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b3d8a760 #0 id=0x7f06003f}
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f06003f (com.gs.maps:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{b3d8a760 #0 id=0x7f06003f}
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
04-18 06:19:16.201: E/AndroidRuntime(2079):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gs.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxx" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.gs.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.gs.maps.TheMap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_the_gay_map" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

The java main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater actionMenue = getMenuInflater();
        actionMenue.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.mapIcon) {
            Intent displayTheMap = new Intent(this, TheMap.class);
                    startActivity(displayTheMap);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Is the "TheMap" an activity in your app and if yes have you declared it in manifest?

Comment: Your error shows that the `PlaceholderFragment` which you are trying to load in `container` is missing. Please post some more code and full logcat error

Comment: @amj here it is `<activity
            android:name="com.gs.maps.TheMap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_the_map" >
        </activity>`

Comment: @chility I asked for the java file code not manifest file.

Comment: @GrIsHu I'm sorry. Just edited it again.

Comment: Make sure your `activity_main` layout contains `FrameLayout` with `container` id.

Comment: Is your `TheMap` activity or fragment?

Comment: @GrIsHu It is there, TheMap is an activity

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue once and I havent really looked in depth at your code but try replacing this (where you are declaring the new intent) with:

```
Intent displayTheMap = new Intent(NAMEOFTHECLASSYOURIN.this, TheMap.class);
```

See if that doesn't do the trick.